# Idiomatic Rust Way to Have Several Ojects Consume an Immutable Reference and Run Concurrently

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, rust, async-await

What's the simplest way to use `async` / `await` (or another way like the `rayon` crate) to have several instances of a structs run a function that takes an immutable reference in parallel?

I have a digital signal processing project where I continually produce a very lightweight struct representing a sample (just a complex number and an index, so 2x `f64` + 1x `usize`), then I want to feed it into several structs representing channels and have them perform expensive computation on the same sample in parallel.  This seems like something that would be relatively straightforward, but I'm having a hard time with it.

Comment: If your struct is as lightweight as you say, you're probably better off just cloning the sample. Otherwise you would need an `Arc` which will probably be more expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing synchronous code, the idiomatic way is to use the [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/) or [`crossbeam`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/) crates, which provides scoped threads that allow you to keep references across thread boundaries.

Scoped threads are not currently possible with `async` / `await`, so in that ecosystem, the idiomatic solution is either to copy the value, or to share it in a reference counted smart pointer such as [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).